# Trouble scraping Barchart.com data into Power Query

Tags: excel, web-scraping, powerquery

I am attempting to scrape this website into Excel's Power Query .

> https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/CBX18/all-futures

When I attempt to pull data into Excel, Power Query cannot find the displayed Brent Crude Oil Table. The desired table displayed here...

[image: Brent Crude Oil Table Pic]

And the result of Power query not finding table here...

[image: Empty Null table Value]

I found this article which goes over digging into the HTML of the desired website through Power Query, however I wasn't able to receive my expected results.

> https://datachant.com/2017/03/30/web-scraping-power-bi-excel-power-query/

[image: Power query after using article]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck and need to figure out how to get this data into a clean Excel spreadsheet. I am open to potentially using a new source or going about the scraping in a different technique1

Comment: I'm not certain if you can scrape data that doesn't actually appear in the HTML of a page (as that table is built out of code components so it can update dynamically). But it does appear they have an option to download their charts as Excel data for what appears to be free with an account. So if you just need the data in a clean Excel format, that might be an option to explore? Might even be possible to autoload the Excel files in through Power Query.

Comment: @Wedge Okay, so I went into Barchart (pictured above) and downloaded the Excel File! The big thing I need to be able to do is have this update automatically for my data entry. This would happen daily. I couldn't find a way to get in through power query since I didn't download the file through power query. Maybe you have any ideas?                                                                          I also am using this link - maybe it might help! https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/Connectin-to-a-Excel-file-from-the-internet/td-p/130654

Comment: That's going to depend entirely on how downloading the file works on the website. I'm not going to setup a log-in myself to try it, so I can't help you there. If Power Query isn't capable you can probably use something like Power Shell to automate downloading the file to a consistent location that PQ would load from. 

I also noticed this section on their site where you can sign up for a their free API, and their sample actually shows them using Power Query to connect to it from Excel https://www.barchart.com/ondemand/free-market-data-api

Comment: @wedge I actually just found Barchart's api yesterday and I think I'm just gonna give that a try. Thanks for the tip because I think that's the best move in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this website which allows 100 free monthly API calls giving you access to not just Brent but also related commodities like WTI, Ethanol and Natural gas. With a free account you can get you an average of 4 datapoints a day (since market is closed on weekends and holidays) for free at different points in time during the day this would allow you to build a far more meaningful data set.

https://commodities-api.com/

This is going to be way, way easier than trying to setup some sort of web-scraping system because the HTML of that web-site could easily change, and the model for this API has been around for quite a while.

If you need old data, there are plenty of downloadable spreadsheets but if you need free up to date data, on how commodities are moving during the day, this is definitely the way to go.

here is an example

```
GET https://commodities-api.com/api/latest
{
"base":USD
"date":2022-12-13
"rates": { 
     "ARABICA COFFEE": 1.65
     "ROBUSTA COFFEE": 1872
     "BRENT OIL": 80.620000000002
     "COCOA": 2546.5
     "CORN": 6.4900000000001
     "COTTON": 0.86000000000001
     "ETHANOL": 2.161
     "LUMBER": 406.5
     "NATURAL GAS": 7.0369999999999
     "RICE": 16.71
     "RUBBER": 1.49
     "SOYBEAN": 14.83
     "SUGAR": 0.1975
     "WHEAT": 325.98179999999
     "WTI OIL": 75.55
     "OAT": 341
     "COAL": 405.00000000001
     "LEAN HOG": 0.8205
     "LIVE CATTLE": 1.5498
     "CANOLA": 871.99999999999
     "GOLD": 1813.3446850696
     "SILVER": 23.790303528843
     "PLATINUM: 1034
     "PALLADIUM: 1887
     "RHODIUM: 12700
     "RUTHENIUM: 750.00000000002
   [170+ world Currencies, Commodities and Cryptocurrencies]
  },
 "unit": per barrel for Oil, per ounce for Metals. Per 10 metric tons for Crude Palm Oil, Per MMBtu for Natural gas, Per Gallon for Ethanol. Per metric ton, per lb or per bushel for Agriculture
 }
```

Other websites are going to continually change small things about their site to avoid scraping, using a free API is a better solution.

Comment: You might even want to pay for a single month and revert to free so that you can pre-load a large dataset, but once you have the initial data-set 100 calls a month lets you check prices 4 of Brent, WTI, Ethanol and Natural Gas, and Crude Palm Oil 4 times a day which should be much more helpful than spreadsheet crunching.

It will also be much faster.